# How to get value of column in OnItemCreated event in telerik C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have telerik grid and I want to get the value of GridBoundColumn in OnItemCreated event

here is my code

```
<telerik:RadGrid OnNeedDataSource="RGrid_NeedDataSource"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rad_RowDataBound" OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated" ID="radgrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" >
    <MasterTableView SkinID="SunSet">
     <Columns>
....
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn  FilterControlWidth="60" DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="Status" HeaderStyle-Width="250px"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
...
</AllColisgTags>
```

and In my C# code

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {

//Here I want to get the value of Status in string I have trid find controls 
e.Item.FindControl("Status");//Did not work
}
}
```

Comment: I have also tried using 
string status = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row.ItemArray[15].ToString(); it also did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn  FilterControlWidth="60" DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="Status" HeaderStyle-Width="250px">
 <asp:Label ID="Status" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

C#

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            Label lbl = (Label)item["TemplateColumn"].FindControl("Status");
            string iss = lbl.Text;

        }
}
```

Comment: not working it gives me this error Type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridTemplateColumn' does not have a public property named 'Label'.

Comment: @Jahangeer - If it doesn't work, how is it the accepted answer?  It looks like Jayesh's solution is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn  FilterControlWidth="60" DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="Status" HeaderStyle-Width="250px"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            string iss = item["Status"].Text; // Status is column Uniquename
        }
}
```

**Note : We can not get/access value of any column/row in ItemCreated event. You have to use ItemDataBound or prerender event for same.**

Please also check below links for more information.

- [RadGrid Event sequence](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-event-sequence.html)
- [RadGrid Events Detail](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/events_t_telerik_web_ui_radgrid.html)